# Проверка на ввод

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите как сделать проверку на ввод? Чтоб вводилась дата в формате только dd/mm/yyyy, не вводилось больше символов чем нужно, не вводились буквы и т.д.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char day[3],month[3],year[5];
    cout<<"Please input the date in dd/mm/yyyy format:";
    cin.get(day,3,'/');
    cin.ignore(100,'/');
    cin.get(month,3,'/');
    cin.ignore(100,'/');
    cin.get(year,5);

    //convert them to int
    int d,m,y;
    d=atoi(day);
    m=atoi(month);
    y=atoi(year);
)
```

Comment: Посмотрите на scanf.

Answer (score 2):

Читайте всю ерунду, которую введет пользователь, затем проверяйте ее регулярными выражениями. Можно оформить в цикл:

```
while(true)
{
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    if(/* Проверка на соответствие */)
        break;
    else
        continue;
}
```

Не давать вводить в консоли - это проблема. Для C++, на сколько я помню, не стандартизирован ввод без буферизации. Можно использовать всякого рода функции вроде _getch() (MS-специфичная из conio.h) в логике конечного автомата, но это не по-джедайски (не переносимо).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю принцип понятен? Год сами сделайте, по своему усмотрению.

```
int dd, mm, yyyy;
cin>>dd>>mm>>yyyy;
if ( mm >= 1 && mm <= 12) {
    if ( mm == /* 1,4,6,9,11 *\ ) 
       // dd == 30 ?
    else if (mm == /*3,5,7,8,12*\)
      // dd == 31
    else if (mm == /*2*\)
      // dd == 28 || dd == 29
    else    
      // error 
}
```

Так же советую начинать отсчет лет с високосного года, тогда можно будет с легкостью определить ошибку ввода 29 февраля в не тот год. Надеюсь разберетесь дальше сами.

И вообще всё это дело запихнуть в класс. У меня вроде бы где-то валяются такие исходники, дома буду поищу.